# JavaScript Regular Expression to prevent cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic

I have and asp application that allows a user to enter url of and external site to reference a pdf, jpg or an .html page.

I am trying to stop XSS such as `abc.com/<script>alert(111)</script>` or `.js` or `.htc` in the address.

```
var re = /[-!$%^*()_+|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,\/]/.test(form1.URL_Input.value);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Retrieve the external resource to verify that it is a valid URL and that the response is acceptable data. Or sanitize the URLs when you display them and generate the links (e.g. URL-encode them).

Comment: UM, JavaScript is the wrong place to be doing the validation on it. Anyone can get around the clientside validation. Hopefully you do the check on the sever also.